# Problema HTML e AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um chat que trabalha com AJAX.
Só que, dependendo de alguns caracteres que o usuário digitar, o AJAX não funciona, não sei porque, mas não funciona.
Logo, preciso retirar o HTML da variável msg, e fazer com que tal variável consiga passar pelo ajax sem causar quaisquer erros.
O .envia_chat é um input text, por isso, pego seu valor através do .val(), eu sei que se eu pegasse com text() estaria tudo resolvido, mas não dá. :(

O código, resumido, está mais ou menos assim:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'chat.php',
   dataType:'JSON',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'msg='+ msg,
   success: function(data){
      //FUNCAO DE SUCESSO
      alert('Msg enviada');
   },
   error: function(data){
      alert('Ocorreu um erro');
   }
});
```

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    function Erro($texto){
        $array = array('status' => $texto);
        return json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    function Sucesso($texto){
        $array = array('status' => $texto);
        return json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) and !empty($_SESSION['login_id']) and isset($_POST['type']) and isset($_POST['lobby']) and is_numeric($_POST['lobby']) == true){
        require('connection.php');
        $id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
        $verifica_user = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM users_buscando WHERE id_user = '$id' and playing = '1' and id_lobby != '0'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($verifica_user) == 1){
            $acao = $_POST['type'];
            $id_lobby = (is_numeric($_POST['lobby'])==true) ? $_POST['lobby'] : NULL;
            $tempo_atual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $busca_user = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
            $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($busca_user);
                    $msg = (isset($_POST['msg'])==true and $_POST['msg'] != '') ? filter_var($_POST['msg'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : NULL;
                    $time = (isset($_POST['time']) == true and $_POST['time'] == 'azul' or $_POST['time'] == 'laranja') ? $_POST['time'] : NULL;
                    $nick = (isset($_POST['nick']) == true) ? $_POST['nick'] : NULL;
                    if($msg != NULL and $time != NULL and $nick != NULL){
                        $insere_msg = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO chat (id_user, content, id_lobby, timestamp, time, nick) VALUES ('$id', '$msg', '$id_lobby', '$tempo_atual', '$time', '$nick')");
                        if($insere_msg === true){
                        echo Sucesso('success');
                        }
                    }



        }else{
            echo Erro('notplaying');
        }
    }else{
        echo Erro('erro');
    }
?>
```

Comment: já tentou `data: "msg=" + encodeURIComponent(msg)`?

Comment: Os caracteres que dao o erro são: < e \. pelo menos os que eu testei deram erro.

Comment: Isso. Basicamente.

Comment: Mas eu recebo um JSON de volta, ele me retorna {status: "success"}

Comment: Vc sabe qual a versão do seu PHP?

Comment: Você não tá fazendo `INSERT` duas vezes com a mesma chave primária?

Comment: versão 7.2.5 do php

Comment: Blz... o erro está algum lugar nesse código PHP... coloca `console.log(data.responseText);` dentro da função error: e veja no console  o erro do PHP que retorna.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a seguinte função JS,

```
function ajustadoEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

Depois, no `$.ajax`, faça

```
....
data: "msg=" + ajustadoEncodeURIComponent(msg),
----
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Os caracteres que tão dando erro, que eu testei são < e \.

Comment: O post completo que eu obtenho é esse: msg=%5C&type=enviaMsg&lobby=10&time=azul&nick=MODERADOR, e mesmo assim dá erro nao estou entendendo.

Comment: Que erro que dá?

Comment: ele entra no error: function() do ajax()

Comment: Eu sei; mas que mensagem vem no `data`?

Comment: vem o status: success que eu programei no backend para retornar.

Comment: Então qual é o problema? Se você codificou o back-end pra retornar "success" quando na verdade está dando erro, não era de você colar o código do back-end por aqui tb?

Comment: Se ele entra no error: function() do ajax, não quer dizer que ele não conseguiu conectar ao arquivo chat.php? eu pensava que era isso

Comment: Não, quer dizer que o back-end deu HTTP Error code diferente de 200.

Comment: oloco. nao sabia. vlw, vou postar o backend ai encima

Comment: Pronto. Postei ai encima

Comment: Você não tá fazendo `INSERT` duas vezes com a mesma chave primária?

Comment: e como iria fazer isso?

Comment: Ué, fazendo INSERT de valores duplicados.

Comment: Acho que entendi o meu problema

Comment: Analisando o código eu vi que eu recebo a Mensagem na variável MSG que possui um filter_var(), esse filtro remove as tags html, etc. Logo, se eu envio uma msg só com um "<", ele remove essa tag, logo a $msg se torna nula, sem valor. logo ele não entra no insert.

Comment: Logoo, como o IF não tem um else, o php não retorna nada, assim, o ajax esperando um retorno JSON, não o recebe, o que ocasiona o error: function()

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o código eu vi que eu recebo a Mensagem na variável MSG que possui um filter_var(), esse filtro remove as tags html, etc. Logo, se eu envio uma msg só com um "<", ele remove essa tag, logo a $msg se torna nula, sem valor. logo ele não entra no if com insert.
Logo, como o IF não tem um else, o php não retorna nada, assim, o ajax esperando um retorno JSON, não o recebe, o que ocasiona o error: function()

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da configuração do servidor, qualquer tentativa de enviar < ou / pelo form pode retornar erro.

Eu uso o próprio jQuery para tratar os caracteres entes de enviar pro servidor.

Teste assim e veja se fica ok:

```
msg = $('<div/>').text(msg).html();
```

Isso faz, por exemplo, que o texto `<script> seja transformado em &lt;script&gt;`

Se for preciso, você pode fazer o decode no servidor e voltar ao texto original.

Comment: que, não entendi ahusahdsaud

Comment: use assim: data: 'msg='+ $('<div/>').text(msg).html(),

Comment: Tá, mas tipo, dá pra explicar da onde surgiu esse <div/>?

Comment: É uma div temporária, nunca entra no DOM. É só pra pegar o conteúdo do input e fazer o encode